# Flash Builder: going to next/previous tab

Tags: tabs, flash-builder, key-bindings

Can I move to next and previous tab using Flash Builder?

On all good OSX applications you can do that with ⌘⌥→ and ⌘⌥←, I've no idea about Windows.

I know ctrl+tab exists and I'm totally **not** interested in that: I just need previous tab and next tab.